# angular material dialog mat-dialog-actions position

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, angular-components

I'm using [Angular Material Dialog component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), with mat-dialog-content and mat-dialog-actions to display a footer with action buttons.

If I set a height of the dialog (e.g 80%), the dialog-actions is weirdly higher than the default.

[Here is a forked stackblitz of an official example](https://angular-material-fixed-height-actions.stackblitz.io)

I just set height: 80%

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, {
  height: '80%',
  width: '520px'
});
```

Here is the result:

[image]

In my opinion that's an issue :) but what's your opinion? Is it possible to easily fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any news on this? I would be interested, too

Answer (score 7):

Github issue tracking this https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4609

Contains cleaner fix (no magic numbers) of DanielHabenicht
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4609#issuecomment-528865962

```
// app.module.ts
import {MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material';
...
providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {panelClass: 'mat-dialog-override'}}
]
...


// overrides.scss or styles.scss
// This fixes https://github.com//issues/4609
.mat-dialog-override {
  height: 0px;
  mat-dialog-container {
    > :first-child {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    mat-dialog-content,
    div[mat-dialog-content] {
      flex-grow: 1;
      max-height: unset;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No magic numbers

Answer (score 5):

You can "stretch" your `mat-dialog-content`.

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content style="height: calc(100% - 96px);">     <-- height of dialog minus title and actions height
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yep i've exactly done your way, I just don't like that magic number in the calc... Didn't find a better solution so far.

Comment: Really nice solution. Works really well! Although it is a strange behavior of mat-dialog that I have to hack it that way to get the buttons sticked to the bottom of the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
.mat-dialog-override {
  mat-dialog-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    mat-dialog-actions {
      margin-top: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @JuNe works really well and is fully responsive. The only thing I have to add is the little tweak I needed to get this working. I had to explicitly set the max-height of **mat-dialog-content** to unset:

```
style="height: calc(100% - 96px);max-height: unset"
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your `mat-dialog-actions` with `style="position: relative; top: 5rem;"` for example.
The value `top` can variable depending height your modal.

Answer (score 0):

`<div mat-dialog-actions style="box-sizing: border-box">` worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Because we wrap our title, content and actions in a form, this will fix the sticky footer issue with a minimal height for our project:

app.module.ts

```ts
import {MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material';
...
providers: [{
  provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {
    panelClass: 'mat-dialog-override',
    hasBackdrop: true, // enable Backdrop
    disableClose: true // disable click and escape for closing
  }
}]
...
```

html:

```html
<ng-template #dialog>
  <form>
    <div mat-dialog-title>Title</div>
    <div mat-dialog-content>...</div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>...</div>        
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

scss:

```scss
.mat-dialog-override {
  mat-dialog-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    > :first-child {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    [mat-dialog-content] {
      flex-grow: 1;
      max-height: unset;
    }
  }
}
```

We use the material attributes to mark the html elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution but didn't find anything. So I get an idea to make this happen. Actually, this solution worked in my case, and I just wanted to share, maybe it will help you.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div>
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>Install Angular</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
      some content
    </mat-dialog-content>
  </div>
  <div style="bottom: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end" >
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Install</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used "flex" to order all my div tags, and after that styling, the last div (action button section) gave me this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB3kM.png).

I hope it will help those who are looking for a solution.